# Using Newsletter module question

Tags: 7, emails

I have just installed the [Newsletter](http://drupal.org/project/newsletter) module, and I am wondering if it is possible to allow users to click on a "subscribe" button, and have them signup for a newsletter, rather than have an administrator manually add subscribers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newsletter module already has this built in by default.

1. Go into permissions and enable "Subscribe newsletters" to all roles.

[image]

2. Then, go to the Blocks UI and enable the "Newsletter: Subscribe" into the region of your choosing.

[image]